# How can env vars be accessed from a server-side script in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, scripting, environment-variables, next.js13

I've got a Next.js app (`create-next-app` v13.4.19 with App Router) where I'm attempting to run a script just before `next build` that fetches data from the Spotify Web API and writes it to a local file. So the script at `src/app/scripts/fetch-music.js` is run which in turn makes use of functions in `src/app/api/spotify.js`. The latter has a `SECRET` declared at the top of the file via `process.env`.

**The problem is that when `fetch-music.js` is run, `SECRET` is `undefined` so the API call fails.**

*Why is this?* I thought that because both files were in the `app` directory (and thus on the server), they would have access to environment variables (written to `.env.local` for local development).

**Further Info:**

The `SECRET` being `undefined` is definitely the issue. I hardcoded the values and the API response succeeded, but obviously this is not acceptable for production. Furthermore, if the logic from `fetch-music.js` is implemented in `src/app/music/page.js` (as was done previously), `music/page.js` has access to `SECRET` via `process.env` and the request is successful.

```
/* scripts from package.json */

{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "npm run music && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "music": "tsx src/app/scripts/fetch-music.js",
    "env-var": "vercel env pull .env.local"
  }
}
```

Comment: Because environment variables are only accessible if the server is running. And even then, only within the application context.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case, but never saw it stated explicitly anywhere. Do you know if there is a way to get around this in Next.js? Is it possible for me to execute the script pre-build without hardcoding the values?
P.S. Please respond as an answer rather than a comment so I can mark as correct.